# I have some issues with graph in ns2

Tags: ns2

I have installed ns2 (ns-2.35) on windows os and finish verification 
successfully. I completely new at ns2 .....

Now, i am in the process to get the graph of the simulation but it appear that it have some problem. I tried to do some tests with other 
scripts that are bundled with ns2. I am still learning....

When  I tried to execute the execute the script of the graph. It is going well 
till one moment when I get this message:

"could't execute "xgraph": no such file or directory while executing"

after that message script goes on doing other things ... but I think 
this is not ok....

Now I am wondering what to do. Make folder "xgraph" ? Where? Or, I need 
to point it out somewhere .... or what to do ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read through the SO-article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It would be really helpful to us if you would provide your code (or the relevant snippets), the full error message as well as describing your efforts solving your issue so we can boil down your problem and provide an actual answer.

Comment: On what os have you installed which version of ns2? Have you added it to your PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the package 'xgraph' installed : Debian, Ubuntu, Mint → `sudo apt install xgraph`

Fedora, CentOS, RHEL : `xgraph-12.1-1.pclos2013.x86_64.rpm` or `xgraph-12.1-7pclos2011.i586.rpm` → https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1asCjtOJKDCGTOvlzxSOb7VMh-6ssd5Vq?usp=sharing → → Download ... and install, example: `# dnf install Downloads/xgraph-12.1-1.pclos2013.x86_64.rpm`

Xgraph simulation examples → xgraph_ns2-files-tcl_01.18.tar.gz
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wa96F4K5XNVuyX7L7mqna7XC55nmBm13/view?usp=sharing

Generally about creating graphs : Information in trace-files.tr can be used for graphs with **ns2 APP-Tool** → http://mohittahiliani.blogspot.dk/2014/10/automated-post-processing-app-tool-for.html → **and** 
https://github.com/WiNG-NITK/APP-Tool

Example = InstG-hasil.tr.png

[image: Example = InstG-hasil.tr.png]